Is it true that mantra cannot be taken from father?
I read somewhere that mantra should not be taken from father. Do any scriptures mention this? Please spill some light on it. Thanks

Yes. Brihat Tantrasara states that one shouldn't take mantradiksha from one's own father. However, the text clarifies that this doesn't applies in the case of the eldest son.
